# Alignment in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to fill a *JasperReports* report's *Detail* area starting from center.
I'm sure my data rows will not exceed the page (A4). For an example..

1. if there is one row existed it must be in the center of the page
2. if the is 5 rows. They are align vertically center in the page.

Both situations must be done using the same *JR* report.
please give some tips.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should illustrate your question with images. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving positioning to your elements to a appropriate x,y coordinates so that your elements are positioned center in your report.